# Java Default Highlighter

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

Im using the `DefaultHightlighter.DefaultHightlighterPainter` to highlight text within a java text pane.
I want to remove all highlights (there could be more than one string highlighted) and want it to return the locations of the strings where the highlight has been removed, so obviously I cant use 
`pseudoCodeTextPane.getHighlighter().removeHighlight(highlight);`

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: please edit your question and post here an http://sscce.org/ that demonstate your issue(s) with Hightlighter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
 Highlighter.Highlight[] highlights = pseudoCodeTextPane.getHighlighter().getHighlights();
 int[] startOffsets = new int[highlights.length];
 int[] endOffsets = new int[highlights.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < highlights.length; ++i) {
     startOffsets[i] = highlights[i].getStartOffset();
     endOffsets[i] = highlights[i].getEndOffset();
 }
 pseudoCodeTextPane.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
 // now do whatever processing you want to do with the highlight locations
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove *all* highlights (I suppose with `removeAllHighlights`) you can `getHighlights` before that and use the information you receive there.