# java highlighting issue

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane that contains a predefined text block. I have a separate thread that highlights certain lines of the text and periodically removes the highlight.

I am highlighting using:
`text.getHighLighter().addHighligh(start,end,highlighter)`
and removing using `text.getHighLighter().removeAllHighLights()`
and i call `text.revalidate()` after it.

Sometimes the highlights are not removed?!

Can someone see a potential issue that I am having?

Comment: please what's wrong with [Java Default Highlighter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078275/java-default-highlighter)

Comment: please show an sscce that demonstrates the problem (btw: revalidate shouldn't be needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your code to highlight/remove in the [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)?

As in

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        text.getHighLighter().removeAllHighLights();
    }
});
```