# highlighting a specific line from jtextpane

Tags: java, swing, highlight

I am trying to highlight a specific lines from `JTextPane`.  Suppose I want to highlight the 5th line from `JTextPane`, how do I get the `indexOf` it to highlight it if the lines are same?

Example content of `JTextPane`, I want to higlight 5th and 11th line from below lines,

```
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from stackoverflow
This text is from google
This text is from yahoo
This text is from yahoo
This text is from yahoo
This text is from yahoo
```

Code:

```
//Code to highlight
//text is jtextpane
final static Color HILIT_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
DefaultHighlighter hilit = new DefaultHighlighter();
DefaultHighlightPainter painter = new  
    DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(HILIT_COLOR);
text.setHighlighter(hilit);

hilit.removeAllHighlights();
String s = text.getText();
try {
    hilit.addHighlight(0, 10, painter);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(TextLines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: why do you down vote?  If you are not clear about the question, there is comment option, you could have commented.

Comment: +1 for editing the messed up text

Answer (score 3):

1) `hilit.removeAllHighlights();` doens't works correctly in all of cases, you have fill [arrays of Highlighter[]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9078442/714968),

2) you have extract `Document` (`Model for JTextComponents`) from `JTextComponents`, [tutorial talking about searching in the Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), then you [can styled text into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/714968)  `JTextPane`(I'm talking about easiest way, there are ways how to determine contents in the concrete row(s), those things could be complicating the resize of JTextComponents)

3) I leaving answer about `Columns` and `Rows` from `JTextComponents` for `@Stanislav`

Comment: +1 for your effort. Still waiting for getting the indexOf repeating line contents

Comment: I _think_ you'd have to use a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to keep track of the line boundaries (offset & length) as they are inserted.

Comment: +1 I think you know all the row/columns related code as well:-) Use Javax.text.Utilities.getRowStart()/getRowEnd()

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your model is [`HTMLDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html), which isn't really line oriented. Alternatively, consider a `JList` and custom renderer using `JTextPane`.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion.  Still waiting for getting the indexOf repeating line contents

Comment: I'm advocating the use of a container that has a line-oriented selection model, but I've commented on my understanding of @mKorbel's [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9778570/230513).